# 'Master of the universe' or 'Nucleus of the universe'

Tags: grammar, expressions, idioms

Can I say:

> No one likes man thinks he is a nucleus of universe.

I've just seen on some website the use of "master of the universe" I'd better use this word?

And please correct my grammar.

Answer (score 3):

Center of the Universe is an acceptable, known term.

edit: you can change your original sentence to:

```
nobody likes people who think that they are the center of the universe
```

or something like that....

Answer (score 0):

To correct your grammar:

> No one likes *a* man *who* thinks he is *the* nucleus of the universe.

You can use *master of the universe* here interchangeably.

But, as the other answer says, *center of the universe* is better than *nucleus*.